# Error when upserting an ID in a lookup field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, upsert, javascript-controller

I'm trying to insert an ID into a lookup field of an object. This is the code of my JS controller so far:

```
var action = component.get("c.saveRent");

action.setParams({ 
    "rent": newRent,
});
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    var state = a.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = 'SUCCESS! Your data was saved!';
        setTimeout(function(){
            location.reload();
        }, 1000);
    }else{
        document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = 'ERROR! error saving the data, check the inputs!';
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action)
```

My code used to pass the ID from the js controller to the apex controller is:

```
action.setParams({"a": bikeID});
action.setCallback(this, function(data){
    component.set("v.bikeIdResult", data.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

And this is the code of my apex controller:

```
public class RentFormController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Rent__c saveRent(Rent__c rent, Id a) {
        system.debug(a);
        rent.Bike_reference__c = 'a034100000Br0ahAAB';
        upsert rent;
        return rent;
    }
}
```

Everything is working just fine, when I set the rent.Bike_reference__c manually, it inserts the data, but when I change it to rent.Bike_reference__c = a, then my lookup field in the object is blank.

My debug output is returning the id correctly.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think your setParams is not right, it should be: `action.setParams({ 
        "rent": newRent,
         "a": bikeID
    });`

Comment: Oh man, thats true, that was my only mistake --' thank you @Praveen, I think is time to take a nap hahahaha

Comment: Well, I'll post the comment as answer, accept it so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `setParams` is not right, you should pass a Object as argument to it which contains all necessary data as key value pair, it should be:

```
action.setParams({ "rent": newRent, "a": bikeID });
```